# Eliminar algún cliente de un archivo

Tags: c, archivo

estoy haciendo un trabajo, me gustaría saber como eliminar algún cliente creado, por ahora, lo que hace mi programa es crear un cliente y guardarlo en archivo .txt, lo que me gustaría saber es como puedo recorrer el fichero y eliminar toda la información que este relacionada con el DNI del cliente, ¿Eso se puede hacer?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <wchar.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #define max_clientes 20
    #define max_viajes 50

     int n,i;
     char nom_archivo[15];
     FILE *archivo;

    struct cliente{
    char dni[9];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellidos[80];
    char direccion[150];
    }clientes[max_clientes]; //Asumimos que habra un maximo de 10 clientes

    void cliente_n(int n)
    {
    clientes[n].dni[0]='\0';
    clientes[n].nombre[0]='\0';
    clientes[n].apellidos[0]='\0';
    clientes[n].direccion[0]='\0';
    return;
    }

     void addcliente()
{

    if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0'){
        printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
        gets(nom_archivo);
        fflush(stdin);
        //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
        archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
        if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            system("cls"); //En windows limpia pantalla
        }else
        {
            int i;
            printf("\n\nArchivo cargado correctamente.|\n");
            for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
                fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
            }
            for(i=0;i<max_clientes;i++)
            {
                if(clientes[i].dni[0]=='\0')
                {
                    //Crear un nuevo cliente y almacenar en el txt mediante fprintf
                    puts("DNI:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].dni);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", clientes[i].dni);

                    puts("Nombre:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].nombre);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].nombre);

                    puts("Apellidos:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);

                    puts("Direccion Introduce los espacios con _:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
            fclose(archivo);
            system("cls");

}

void guardar(){
    printf("\nIntroduzca el nombre del fichero.\n\t");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(nom_archivo);
                archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"wb");
                fwrite(clientes,sizeof(clientes),1,archivo);
                //fwrite(viajes,sizeof(viajes),1,archivo);     viajes no se almacena correctamente y genera conflicto con clientes
                fclose(archivo);
                system("cls");


}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); //De esta manera podremos mostrar por consola caracteres especiales

 for(n=0;n<max_clientes;n++){
    cliente_n(n);
 }
    char select;


    do{
    printf("\n\t*************************************************\n\t*\t\t      MENU\t\t\t*\n\t*************************************************\n");
    printf("\t*  a.-Nuevo cliente\t\t\t\t*\n");
    printf("\t*  b.-Guardar fichero\t\t\t\t*\n");
    printf("\t*************************************************");
    printf("\n\tIntroduce la opción que desea ejecutar: ");
        scanf("%c", &select);
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");

    switch (select)
        {
            case 'a':
                addcliente();
                break;
            case 'b':
                guardar();
                break;
            case 'h':
                break;

        }

     }
     while (select != 'h');
     printf("\n\nHas cerrado el programa correctamente\n\n");

fflush(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que he intentado es hacerlo mediante tokems, esto es un ejemplo que he buscado por internet y he intentado modificarlo para mi caso

```
void decrementar_numero_clientes (unsigned short int n)
{
    int m;
    char token[tm_dni];
    strcpy(token,clientes[n].dni);
    strtok(token,"_");
    for(m=0;m<max_clientes;m++)
    {
        if(strcmp(clientes[m].dni,token)==0)
        {
            clientes[m].dni[tm_dni]--;
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Bueno lo que voy ha hacer es en vez de crear todos los clientes en un txt voy a crear por cada cliente un txt y que tenga el formato nombre_cliente.txt, después para eliminarlo pondré un remove y que borre todo el txt

Comment: Una forma de "borrar" el cliente seria "guardar todos menos ese". Quiero decir, vas leyendo el archivo, y si ese registro NO ES el que quieres borrar, lo guardas en un segundo archivo temporal. Luego al final del proceso, cambias el nombre del segundo archivo por el primero. (no es muy correcto, pero para aprendizaje esta bien)